# Cognitive Services - Error Create FaceList and PersonGroup AZURE

Tags: php, azure, azure-cognitive-services

Could you help me I'm studying about cognitive services using the azure service, but I'm having some mistakes using the forncecido model in the documentation

```
                <?php
            // This sample uses the Apache HTTP client from HTTP Components (http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/)
            require_once 'HTTP/Request2.php';
            // Replace <Subscription Key> with a valid subscription key.
            $ocpApimSubscriptionKey = '98471c5c832e466688890f6c86f6c88d'; 


            $request = new Http_Request2('https://brazilsouth.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/facelists/{faceListId}');
            $url = $request->getUrl();

            $headers = array(
                // Request headers
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' => $ocpApimSubscriptionKey ,
            );

            $request->setHeader($headers);

            $parameters = array(
                // Request parameters
                'faceListId' => 'sahara'
            );

            $url->setQueryVariables($parameters);

            $request->setMethod(HTTP_Request2::METHOD_PUT);

            // Request body
            $request->setBody("{body}");

            try
            {
                $response = $request->send();
                echo $response->getBody();
            }
            catch (HttpException $ex)
            {
                echo $ex;
            }

            ?>
```

I run this script in php and it gives me the following error

{"error":{"code":"BadArgument","message":"Request body is invalid."}}

could you tell me what I'm doing wrong, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [FaceList - Create API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f3039524b#php), the body format is

```
{
    "name": "sample_list",
    "userData": "User-provided data attached to the face list."
}
```

We need to send body with following way, then it should work.

```
// Request body
$request->setBody('{"name":"facelistName","userData":"it is optional"}'); //replace it with your name and userData
```

If want to reference `'HTTP/Request2.php';`, we need to install `http_request2`

```
pear install http_request2
```

How to install the PEAR package manager, please refer to this [link](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php).

Demo code:

```
<?php
// This sample uses the Apache HTTP client from HTTP Components (http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/)
require_once 'HTTP/Request2.php';

$request = new Http_Request2('https://xxx.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/facelists/{faceListId}');
$url = $request->getUrl();

$headers = array(
    // Request headers
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' => 'xxxxxxxxxx', //replace it with your key
);

$request->setHeader($headers);

$parameters = array(
    'faceListId' => 'facelistId'
);

$url->setQueryVariables($parameters);

$request->setMethod(HTTP_Request2::METHOD_PUT);

// Request body
$request->setBody('{"name":"facelistName","userData":"it is optional"}');//replace it with your name and userData

try
{
    $response = $request->send();
    echo $response->getBody();
}
catch (HttpException $ex)
{
    echo $ex;
}

?>
```